# dynamic entities from entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

the following query

```
SELECT 
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    p.rows AS RowCounts,
    SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB, 
    SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB, 
    (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
GROUP BY 
    t.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY 
    t.Name
```

returns a table that i want to display on the UI from entity framework. As you can see the table cannot be created because it's dynamic.

Can this be done using `Entity Framework`?

Comment: yes that statement can be written in linq with EF

Comment: and return the data as anonymous type?

Comment: Create a view for this or execute with ExecuteSqlQuery.

Comment: I would do it with an anon type but as pawel says you can also use a view

Comment: How is this dynamic?  It will return 5 columns with 5 known data types.  I don't see how this is different than any query that you would to EF-up.

Answer (score 0):

Use Context.Database.SqlQuery(yoursql) and use the generic overload and supply a custom type. EF will populate the model with the selected columns values, so give the model properties the same names as the columns (e.g. TableName, RowCounts)